# Conditionally including Flex libraries (SWCs) in mxmlc/compc ant tasks

Tags: apache-flex, build-process, mxmlc, compc

I have been struggling trying to figure out how to conditionally include Flex libraries in an ant build based on a property that is set on the command line.  I have tried a number of approaches with the `<condition/>` task, but so far have not gotten it to work.  Here is where I am currently.

I have an init target that includes condition tasks like this:

```
 <condition property="automation.libs" value="automation.qtp">
  <equals arg1="${automation}" arg2="qtp" casesensitive="false" trim="true"/>
 </condition>
```

The purpose of this task is to set a property that determines the name of the patternset to be used when declaring the  implicit fileset on a mxmlc or compc task.  The pattern set referenced above is defined as:

```
 <patternset id="automation.qtp">
  <include name="automation*.swc"/>
  <include name="qtp.swc"/>
 </patternset>
```

The named patternset is then referenced by the mxmlc or compc task like this:

```
<compc>
 <compiler.include-libraries dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs" append="true">
  <patternset refid="${automation.libs}"/>
 </compiler.include-libraries>
</compc>
```

This doesn't appear to work.  At least the SWC size does not indicate that the additional automation libraries have been compiled in.  I want to be able to specify a command line property that determine which patternset to use for various types of builds.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't get `<patternset>` to work correctly, you might want to take a look at the `<if>` `<then>` and `<else>` tasks provided by ant-contrib.  We ended up doing something like this:

```
<target name = "build">
    <if>
        <equals arg1="automation.qtp" arg2="true"/>
        <then>
            <!--
               - Build with QTP support.
               -->
        </then>
        <else>
            <!--
               - Build without QTP support.
               -->
        </else>
    </if>
</target>
```

There is some duplication of build logic between the if and else branch, but you can factor some of that out if you wrap `<mxmlc>` with a macrodef.

Comment: This is a great suggestion.  I followed a similar approach earlier naively thinking that <if> would be allowed within the <mxmlc> task, which of course it wasn't.  I hadn't considered wrapping the mxmlc in an <if>.  That would probably work, however, there are about 15 modules that are build in this script, and I'd have wrap it that many times.  I was looking for an approach that would allow me to set the include libraries once and have it picked up automatically across all the <mxmlc> tasks in the ant project.  If I don't hear any alternatives, I'll have to give this a try.  Thanks.

Comment: We worked around some of the duplication by creating a build-all target that used ant-contrib's <foreach> task and matched all *.mxml files in a particular directory.  The <foreach> then called our build-single target which would conditionally include the QTP libs.

Answer (score 0):

The mxmlc task supports loading [configuration files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67670-7ff2.html) `<load-config filename="path/to/flex-config.xml" />`. So, generate the config xml on the fly, by combining the [echoxml](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoxml.html) task and if-then-else.

```
<echoxml file="path/to/flex-config.xml">
    <flex-config>
        <compiler>
            <library-path append="true">
                <path-element>${lib.qtp}</path-element>
            </library-path>
        </compiler>
    </flex-config>
</echoxml>
```

If your needs are more complicated, you could even generate several xml configs and `<load-config ... />` them all.

Personally, I find any logic very terse and ugly to write using Ant's conditions or if-then-else, XML is not a pretty language to use for programming. Luckily, it's possible to use more flexible approach - write a script to produce the config xml, before calling mxmlc. E.g. use the [script](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) task with your favorite scripting language

```
<script language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        // Create your XML dynamically here.
        // Write that XML to an external file.
        // Later, feed that file to mxmlc using `<load-config ... />`.
    ]]>
</script>
```