# Advice for learning to compile pure AS3 projects with Ant

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-construction, ant, mxmlc

I'm interested in breaking free of IDEs with my ActionScript development. It seems that using Ant with mxmlc is the preferred way of doing this; however, I've never used Ant or the compiler directly before.

Information of note that may or may not be important to know:

- I develop primarily on a Mac
- I author my files in vi
- Projects are versioned with git
- I use swcs for visual assets

Is there a good resources for learning Ant in this regard? Also, are there any suggestions or pitfalls I should be aware of as I begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I don't know exactly what kind of answer you expect but I will give it a shot.

1. That's no problem at all. Ant supports Mac OS out of the box, so you should be up and running in no time.
2. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with ant, or could pose any problem at what you are trying to achieve. You could use any editor for all ant cares..
3. Git and ant are not working well together. You will have to either use some [external](http://aniszczyk.org/2011/05/12/git-ant-tasks-via-jgit/) tasks for that or use the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task and write your own little push/pull/commit scripts.
4. For this and the general guidelines please have a look at :

[Conditionally including Flex libraries (SWCs) in mxmlc/compc ant tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052453/conditionally-including-flex-libraries-swcs-in-mxmlc-compc-ant-tasks)

The ant [manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/), and always try to remember that ant is not a programming language, and should not be treated as such. Good luck with your task!